# Q_PROPERTY of type float on custom widget does not appear in the Property Editor

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator, qtwidgets

I'm working on a custom widget and wanted to make some float type properties. Unfortunately it doesn't seem that Qt Creator is a fan of those float type properties and isn't showing them in the property editor. All of my other properties work fine (int, bool, QString). Here's an example of how I declare the properties.

In the header file:

```
Q_PROPERTY( float Value
            READ getValue
            WRITE setValue
            RESET resetValue )
float Value;

// ...

float getValue();
void resetValue();
void setValue( float value );
```

And in the source file:

```
float MyWidget::getValue()
{
    return Value;
}
void MyWidget::resetValue()
{
    Value = 0;
}
void MyWidget::setValue( float value )
{
    Value = value;
}
```

Is there something special that needs to be done before floats can be used for widget properties?

Comment: @thuga Just tried double and that seems to work. I hadn't tried that previously as I saw a thread elsewhere complaining about the same problem with both float and double, so I just assumed it wouldn't work. Feel free to make your brief comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double` should work as for example [`QWidget::windowOpacity`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop) is a double type and it is displayed in the property editor.
I am not sure why `float` doesn't work, but usually when some properties don't display in the property editor it is because it doesn't know what editor to use.

Comment: I'm just going to add that long has the same issue. Only int is supported for properties which will show in the form editor. This seems really bizarre to me.